# Is there any way I can do an android screencast to my computer?

Tags: wireless, android, screencast

I know there are a lot of third party screencast apps and such, but I've seen android cast to a chromecast, and wonder if it is possible to do that to my computer running ubuntu. I think it runs over wifi, so is there a way I could do this with just the wifi card in my computer?

Comment: I found leapcast, but that only seems to let me (with very little reliability, mind you) sometimes cast a youtube video or google play books, not completely like the chromecast